# Non selectable text is not selected, but IS copied

Tags: css, google-chrome

Here is my code for making some parts of text unselectable (`class="no"`):

HTML:

```
<div class="mono">
  <span class="no">1. </span>first row<br/>
  <span class="no">2. </span>second row<br/>
  <span class="no">3. </span>third row<br/>
  <br/>
  <span class="no">NO! </span>YES! <span class="no">NO! </span>YES! 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mono {
    font-family: monospace;
}

.no {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
     -khtml-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
         -o-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}
```

After selecting a text with unselectable parts:

[image]

I copied it to the clipboard.

In *Firefox* it works as expected — after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> just the selected text will be in the clipboard:

Firefox:

> `first row`
> `second row`
> `third row`
>
> `YES! YES!`

But in *Chrome* the unselected text is copied to the clipboard *with the surrounding unselectable text, too*:

Chrome:

> `first row`
> `2. second row`
> `3. third row`
>
> `NO! YES! NO! YES!`

**I need to obtain the correct behavior in *Chrome*** (preferably *without* using JavaScript).

You may try it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edaqyL45/), separately from *Firefox* and from *Chrome*.

If you have any suggestions how to reach my goal, please share them here.

Comment: Appears to be this bug? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=147490

Comment: @DannyParker Yes, exactly, thanks. For now I need to find some workaround.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to mangle the page so the selectable stuff is contiguous, and then use some layout shenanigans to re-layout the elements in the order you want.